# Alert dialog display even when the application is not running

Tags: java, android

I want to notify the user of my app when he receives special news (from my app).
How can i display some kind of a messeage to the user, even if my app is running in the background (or not running at all if possible).

I want him to be notified by text, and sound.

Thanks.

Comment: i think its C2DM push notification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write a [service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) for doing this. Then in your service code use [Notification](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html) class to show text and sound alerts.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Broadcast Receiver`, to notify abt some action. Like updates, sms, or abt indicate when booting of a phone completes,etc... BroadCast Receiver works on the principle of Publisher and Subscriber pattern.

Answer (score 1):

If your app is not running and you want to do something you'll need some kind of broadcast receiver to receive a trigger.
Probably what you'll end up doing is starting up at device boot, to schedule some stuff. [This answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784441/trying-to-start-a-service-on-boot-on-android) should get you into the right direction

After that, the best way to notify the user is with notifications (or Toast messages if you're a great fan;)) 
Have a look at
[Status Bar Notifications](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)